# How to add key without expiration date

Tags: apt

When installing apps from Open Suse Build service one has to add a key like this

```bsh
curl "https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:manuelschneid3r/public_key" | sudo apt-key add -
```

However users of my app complain that the keys expire every now and then. How does one add a key without an expiration date?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu. The version does not matter. It should work for all of them. At least those listed here: https://build.opensuse.org/project/show/home:manuelschneid3r

Comment: You told us how your users download the public key and which versions of Ubuntu your app works in. Now [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1396112/edit) and tell us how you created the private-public key pair and which distro and version of Linux you did it in. Did you develop the app and create the keys in OpenSuse?

Comment: @user68186 thb I cant tell. this is done automatically by the open suse build system. does it really matter?

Comment: Can you edit the private key by downloading it to your Ubuntu computer and upload it again?

Comment: I cannot modify it afaik

Comment: Then you can't change or remove the expiration date. And this question is not about Ubuntu.

Comment: Is it really the case that the key comes with an expiry date or is it rather the system which add a system wide expdate? to my knowledge a key is a string of random letters, nothing more.

Comment: Google how to change gpg expiry date.

Comment: For me, this is the error I get with your key: _The repository 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_21.10  InRelease' is not signed._ My only guess is that you are missing [this part](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-secure.8.en.html#ARCHIVE_CONFIGURATION) which details how to sign the `InRelease` file. I'm not sure how the repo is configured, but you can probably track down the build master and let them know about this

Comment: Thats weird. For most of the users this works flawlessly. Only after two years or so the key expires.

Comment: If it helps, I imported your key like this: `sudo apt-key add ~/Downloads/Release.key`, and when I run `apt-key list`, I see the following: https://i.imgur.com/4NWlb3Y.png. I got `Release.key` from the [xUbuntu_21.10](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_21.10/) repo

Comment: Why dont you import the key as in the question above?

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r it's the same thing. What I did above reads the key from a file, the method you show in your question reads the key from stdin. To get the key, I did `curl "https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:manuelschneid3r/public_key" --output ~/Downloads/Release.key`